# Qty of codes in one string occurring with codes in second string

Tags: powerbi

I've got a table that looks like this

[image]

I want to check how many times each code from R codes occurs for each code in D codes.

The result of this in the matrix should look like this.

[image]

Does anyone have an idea how to approach this?

Comment: Can you please provide the sample data in table format [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302471/how-to-put-tables-in-stack-overflow)

Comment: Hi, Link to sample data https://drive.google.com/file/d/18MCyLunt-kX3lUqDOD77wfhtrX7ojkNY/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps you should follow.

1. Load the data into the Power Query Editor, the "Transform data" button.
2. Add an index column.
3. Split the **D Codes** column by delimiter (being space) and do so on each occurence.
4. Select the **Index** and the **R Codes** columns, then select the **Unpivot Other Columns** option. You want to unpivot all the newly split out D Code columns.
5. Remove the unneeded **Attribute** column.
6. Split the **R Codes** column exactly how you did the first time to the D Codes column.
7. Select the **Index** and **Value** (the one with the D01, D02, etc. values) columns, and then select the **Unpivot Other Columns** option again. It is IMPORTANT that you unpivot in this way.
8. Remove the new **Attribute** column.
9. Rename the columns if desired. Proceed to step 10 or 11.
10. (Optional): At this point, the data is probably in its optimal format. (You might want to remove the index and add a new one.) You could load the data from Power Query Editor into the Report View of Power BI and make your desired chart by building out a matrix visual. The rows should be the **D Codes** field. And your columns for the matrix should be the **R Codes** field. You can use the **Index** column in the Values and set it to count.
11. (Optional): If you want the data to look like your desired table within the Report View of Power BI, then you need to add this additional step. Select the **R Codes** column and select the **Pivot Column** option. Pivot onto the **Index** column. In the "Advanced options" area, select the "Count (All)" option. That should be it.

I have pasted the M code from my Advanced Editor so that you can get a good idea.

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"D Codes", type text}, {"R Codes", type text}}),
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Changed Type", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Added Index", "D Codes", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(" ", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"D Codes.1", "D Codes.2", "D Codes.3", "D Codes.4"}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"D Codes.1", type text}, {"D Codes.2", type text}, {"D Codes.3", type text}, {"D Codes.4", type text}}),
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type1", {"R Codes", "Index"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{"Attribute"}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter1" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Removed Columns", "R Codes", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(" ", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"R Codes.1", "R Codes.2", "R Codes.3", "R Codes.4"}),
    #"Changed Type2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter1",{{"R Codes.1", type text}, {"R Codes.2", type text}, {"R Codes.3", type text}, {"R Codes.4", type text}}),
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns1" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type2", {"Index", "Value"}, "Attribute", "Value.1"),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns1",{"Attribute"}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Removed Columns1", List.Distinct(#"Removed Columns1"[Value.1]), "Value.1", "Index", List.Count)
in
    #"Pivoted Column"
```